# TYPO3 tx_news translation into german

Tags: typo3, tx-news

i use the TYPO3 Extension news from Georg Ringer (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/news/). Everything works as it should, but I would like to have a German translation. Everything I tried so far did not work.

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Best regards
Sascha

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:

1. Login into TYPO3 Backend
2. Go to module "Languages"
3. Add "German" with the button "+"
4. Click on "Download" in the right of the "German" line
5. Wait a minute
6. Done. The German translation should be in FE and BE

Comment: don't forget to clear the frontend cache after downloading the new language

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. That's exactly what I've already done, but the texts in tx_news are still in English and not in German.

Comment: Are you sure that your TypoScript is correct for displaying German text? `config.language = de` is mandatory.

Comment: Hello Thomas, yes i think. config { sys_language_uid = 0 language = de locale_all = de_DE .....

Comment: I have uninstalled the German language package and then reinstalled and now works.